# How to set a row color based on it's field value.from client side in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using grid view to display a table, and using onRowDataBound to execute a function which sets color based on the field value

function definition is like this

```
    {
        e.Row.Cells[3].Visible = false;
        if (e.Row.Cells[3].Text == "0")
            {
                e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

            }
    }
```

I want to know how this could be done from client side, instead of server side.

Answer (score 0):

### Found this basic exemple for client side

Try ajust it to work with your data in the views and add the you can put color via css i guess.

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100px">StuId
            </td>
            <td style="width: 150px">StuName
            </td>
            <td style="width: 100px">Course
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <asp:GridView AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="StuId" HeaderText="StuId" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="StuName" HeaderText="StuName" ItemStyle-Width="150px" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Course" HeaderText="Course" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Acticle : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/249155/Rows-and-Columns-Merging-in-ASP-NET-GridView-Contr